# Azure Databricks SCIM provisioning

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I am planning to enable SCIM provisioning for my Azure Databricks resource. It is mentioned in the MS Doc that it is always recommended to enable SCIM at the account level and not at the individual workspace level
So now if i enable SCIM provisioning for  Databricks at the account level and register an application in Azure AD how do i give access to various groups to individual workspaces

Say i create a group --> "Finance-Admin"  and add this group to the Azure AD application, then members belonging to this group will get access to Databricks.

But what if i want to create two groups, "Finance-Admin" and another "Finance-Users"

Now i want to give "Finance-Admin" users permission to the Finance workspace so that they can create clusters and add node pools

For the users for the "Finance-Users" group i want to only give permission to restart clusters in Finance workspace

So how do i do these things if i am using Terraform to provision clusters and provide cluster permissions also using IaC

Is this achievable with SCIM provisioning at the account level or whatever i am trying to achieve i need to do SCIM provisioning at the Workspace level ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do that using account-level SCIM synchronization - SCIM connector will sync groups and users into the Account Console, and then you can assign groups to the specific workspaces. With Databricks Terraform provider account-level users/groups are assigned to workspaces using the [mws_permission_assignment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/mws_permission_assignment) resource.

Comment: Right now i have local accounts in our Prod workspace. We are creating a new DEV environment and trying to do SCIM provisioning at the Databricks account level. Once SCIM provisioning is enabled at the Databricks account level, will it take off all the local accounts from the Prod Workspaces?

Comment: No, until you start to assign users/groups explicitly. But the actual behavior may depend on some factors if you have `external_id` synchronized into local workspace or not